# get string from JSON file c /cli

Tags: c++-cli

i have a json file which i need to parse and get some string from it is there any code or example in managed c++ (c++/cli) thanks. 
here is an extract from my json file i nedd to get all Nodes

{  "ID": "{15DFD536-EC23-4624-803E-5AA719DC7A85}",  " Nodes": [   -0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0,   -0.01,   0.01 ]}

Comment: Using the [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) library is boilerplate, works fine from C++/CLI as well.

Comment: +1 Json.NET is the way to go, the best JSON library in .Net. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample using **[Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)**:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace Newtonsoft::Json;

ref class MyData
{
    public: Guid ID;
    public: array<double>^ Nodes;
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    String^ json = "{ \"ID\": \"{15DFD536-EC23-4624-803E-5AA719DC7A85}\", \"Nodes\": [ -0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0, -0.01, 0.01 ]}";

    MyData^ data = JsonConvert::DeserializeObject<MyData^>(json);

    Console::WriteLine("ID: {0}\nNodes: {1}", data->ID, String::Join(",", System::Linq::Enumerable::Cast<Object^>(data->Nodes)));

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
ID: 15dfd536-ec23-4624-803e-5aa719dc7a85
Nodes: -0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0,-0.01,0.01
```